# Auto-terminate the EC-2 instance after particular duration using SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any way to terminate the EC-2 instance after a particular time like 2 hours from the time of creation.

I am using NodeJS to perform the operations on AWS EC-2.

Is there any parameter I have to pass when I create the instance or I need to create a separate function for this method like some built-in method for auto-terminating the EC-2 instance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using AWS Lambda anonymous functions. You can have Lambda create your EC2 instance, and then have it delete it 2 hours later through use of a 'step function'. More info here: [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to have the instance terminate itself.

Upon startup, it can run a simple script like:

```
sleep 7200
sudo shutdown -h
```

To have the instance terminate on the `sudo shutdown` command, set the **Shutdown Behavior** (when the instance is launched) to `Terminate`.

This script could be triggered from a User Data script when the instance is started. Run the script in the background, such as:

```
./shutdown_script &
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that the instance is responsible for turning itself off. Any other option would require a timer to be set somewhere (eg Amazon CloudWatch Events), which starts to get more tricky.

Comment: Thanks, John. Can you tell me how to achieve this with the help of Javascript?

Comment: This method does not require JavaScript. Where would you expect the JavaScript to run?

Comment: I am creating using SDK.
`var instanceParams = {

    ImageId: 'ami-d1232c',

    InstanceType: 't2.micro',

    KeyName: 'production',

    MinCount: 1,

    MaxCount: number,

    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: 'terminate',

    BlockDeviceMappings: [{

      DeviceName: '/dev/sda1',

      Ebs: {

        DeleteOnTermination: true

      }

    }]

  };



  var instancePromise = new AWS.EC2({ apiVersion: '2016-11-15' }).runInstances(instanceParams).promise();
`